# How to find start and end times where a particular condition is continuously true in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, grouping, gaps-and-islands

I've run into an interesting problem, I'm attempting to tie energy usage logs back to particular events within a production environment. Our production data has been logging for about 6 months, the logged data inserts a record every 30 secs or on change. within these logs 'factory mode' is also logged with the following structure:

```
t_stamp             tag     value
----------------------------------
11/12/17 21:00:00   mode    10
11/12/17 21:00:30   mode    10
11/12/17 21:01:00   mode    80
11/12/17 21:01:30   mode    80
11/12/17 21:02:00   mode    80
11/12/17 21:02:30   mode    80
….                  mode    80
12/12/17 03:03:30   mode    80
12/12/17 03:04:00   mode    80
12/12/17 03:04:30   mode    80
12/12/17 03:05:00   mode    10
12/12/17 03:05:30   mode    10
12/12/17 03:06:00   mode    10
12/12/17 03:06:30   mode    10
```

I'd like a query to return a result like:

```
row    mode    start_t_stamp        end_time_stamp
------------------------------------------------------
1      10      11/12/17 21:00:00    11/12/17 21:00:30
2      80      11/12/17 21:01:00    12/12/17 03:04:30
3      10      12/12/17 03:05:00    12/12/17 03:06:30
```

once I have the start and end timestamps i'll be able to extract the energy usage data for each of the mode of the factory eg, idle, warmup, ready_standby, production etc and form an average usage for each mode, but I'm stuck at the every first step, I've looked at partition by, read articles on islands and gaps but I can't find an example where to data is logged in this way. any suggestions would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a gaps and islands problem. If you have window functions available then you can use the following

```
select value, 
       min(t_stamp) start_t_stamp , 
       max(t_stamp) end_time_stamp 
from
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by value order by t_stamp) - 
              row_number() over (order by t_stamp) grn
    from data
) t
group by value, grn
```

The basic idea is that the consequent rows with the same `value` will have the same `grn`. When you have this you can group them easily.